# TestNg.xml File not running in Class sequence order

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

[image: Xml code]

TestNg.xml File not running in Class sequence order

All test cases running parallel

Like this way

```
test1 from MyTests1 class
test3 from MyTests2 class
test2 from MyTests1 class
test4 from MyTests2 class


On My 1st Class I have 13 test cases
On My 2st Class I have 5 test cases
On My 3st Class I have 3 test cases
```

So sequence suppose to be  1st 13 then 5 then last 3 but all are running parallel

Comment: try setting priority for each tests and you will see it is running in sequence. `@Test (priority=1)`

Comment: #Pratik  I already Define @Test (priority=1) for all test cases but still it running parallelly.
When I ran class separately then it work fine but when i ran all classes then I got problem

Comment: try setting group="" and dependsongroup="" with the priority.

Comment: Actually all my test cases are independent  so dependsongroup is not used for me.

Comment: I mean as you said your First class has 13 test cases you can add all that in one group and then your second is one group and it is dependsongroup First class. It doesn't mean they are connected its just way to execute in certain flow.

Comment: Something wrong with priority u added(double check it Test NG doesn't see it), because they way priority works, if u added priority u should never be able to run your tests in parallel even if you added parallel settings, this is limitation of TestNG.

Comment: @IPolnik  my testng priority is double check and its correct when I ran  a single class then test cases run as per the  priority  but when I ran all the classes then it run parallel

Comment: in testNG.xml set up each class as separate test, thats how it structured in my tests and it's running one by one. <test name="1st test">
        <classes>
            <class name="1st class"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="2nd test">
        <classes>
            <class name="2nd class name"/>
        </classes>
    </test>